# Passing variables from one controller to another with laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

Is it possible when redirect from one controller to another also to pass variables? What I mean is that I have submit function and after submit I make redirect to url. Then in other controller trying to display some info based on variables. This is the redirect from first controller

```
return Redirect::to('/cart/payment/order/' . $order->order_id . '+' . $order->user_id);
```

then in second controller this

```
public function paymentView() {


    $order = Order::where('order_id', $orderId)->first();

    if (!$order) {
        App::abort(404);
    }

    $userID         = $order['user_id'];            
    $orderID        = $order['order_id'];
}
```

Question is how to get `$user_id` and `$order_id` now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your route declaration should accept them, something like this, depending on your route:

`Route::get('cart/payment/order/{orderID}/{userID}'...`

Then Laravel will automatically inject them in your controller method:

`public function paymentView( $orderID, $userID, ) {`

And I recommend your URL to be with slash not with plus sign:

`return Redirect::to('/cart/payment/order/' . $order->order_id . '/' . $order->user_id);`

Comment: Ok, I've made changes as you suggest me but I've got `production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: orderId'...` when I trying to query here ` $order = Order::where('order_id', $orderId)->first();`

Comment: @JordanVit make sure the variable name in the route and in the controller method is matching the one you use in the where clause.

Comment: Yes, it was `orderID` instead of `orderId`. Thanks